# Getting array length with d3

Tags: arrays, d3.js

I'm having trouble returning an array length. I have an array as follows:

```
var colorsquares = [
                [3.3, 28, -1.5, 13, 857, 3, 5, 6, 7, 5, ["#b2dbbb","#d2e6c1"]],
                [1.3, 18, -1.5, 13, 857, 3, 5, 6, 7, 5, ["#c2dccc","#d2fdc1"]]
                ];
```

and I'm using the last values to color divs

```
d3.select("#colorBox")
          .selectAll("div")
          .data(d[10])
          .enter()
          .append("div")
          .style("background-color", function(d) { 
               return d; 
           })
           .style("width", function(d) { 
               return (d.length + 1) + "px"; 
           })
           ;
```

The colors are coming out right but I'm not getting what I want for the width. Instead of 2, I'm getting 8.

Comment: Also just as a possible tip (may or may not be relevant to your case, but I'll throw it out there in case), have you considered using an object instead of an array? i.e. `{ radius: 3.3, xPosition: 28, whatever: 357, ......, colors: ["#b2dbbb","#d2e6c1"] }`. That way you get much more flexibility and reliability: `dd.colors` is much easier to understand & less likely to break than `dd[10]`...!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a D3 styling function:

```
.style("width", function(d) { 
    return (d.length + 1) + "px"; 
})
```

, that first parameter (which you have called `d`) represents the individual array element, for example `"#b2dbbb"` or `"#d2e6c1"`. D3 passes the first array element (`"#b2dbbb"`) to the first `div`, second (`"#d2e6c1"`) to the second `div`, and so on. So when you ask for `d.length + 1`, you are asking for the length of the string `"#b2dbbb"` + 1 which is, indeed, 8.

**I think your confusion comes because you have used the name `d` for two separate purposes, and one is hiding the other. You use it as the parameter within the function, but also as a reference to `colorsquares[0]` or `colorsquares[1]` (are these in some kind of loop or something? I can't be more specific because you haven't posted all your code.)**

**For example, change the OUTER `d` (the one you are referring to when you say `.data(d[10])`) to be called `dd` (or a better name, ideally). Then, in the background color function you are right to say**

```
return d
```

**But in the width function, I think you are looking for**

```
return (dd[10].length + 1) + "px";
```